# Styling br-tags: possibility using moz feature in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I know the styling of br-tags has been talked about [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css).

Now i wonder if there is a possibility to style it using firefox's built in moz-features.
Anybody got a suggestion for browser built in features using firefox or webkit?

Comment: are you sure you have read well the link you provided!?

Comment: i thought i did - i see no standard way of doing this - but there might have been some special built-in functions built-in somewhere

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to style `br`. If you need extra space between elements, use `margin` or `padding` instead. And define desired size in your `css`.

Unless, you specifically need to break parts in a `paragraph` in an example of a poem, you would not be using `br` tags. Even then, there would be no reason to style the tags.

The only time you would want to use `br` for adding space would be in `email html coding` since `margin` is not supported properly throughout email clients.

**NOTE**

Even if you wanted to style `br`, no CSS properties would take effect.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        br{border-bottom: 1px solid red; background: red; height: 200px; width: 300px; display: inline;}
    </style>
```

Comment: For our special use case it is necessary to style brs, because the aim is not to have extra space between elements

Comment: You can't style brs. If the aim is not to have space, do not use brs because thats their purpose. Use `<span>`. If you really need brs for some reason, use a different tag like span and then write a converter that changes all spans to brs. Can be done with simple regex

Comment: We had a special usecase and we needed those brs. The br styling was just a feature to show them when switching a "show-br-elements"-button. I didn't find a way to style them to our needs. It is possible with limits in IE though. So our solution was a bit more complicated using another element for the styling.