# css: how to make <br> not highlighted when selecting text (in Chrome)

Tags: html, css

I changed the text highlight color using `::selection`, which works pretty in my page. However, I found the Chrome behaves different from FF, which highlight the `<br>` with default blue color instead of the color I set for all the elements. FF doesn't hightlight the  `<br>` so it works fine.

I tried to override the `::selection` for `<br>`, doesn't work; Tried to use `user-select:none;`, doesn't work either; Tried `display:none;`, which simply made my `<br>` all disappeared...

Any idea?

Comment: I think it may just be a bug, but I hope someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: @bookcasey I suppose this is a bug and I will submit it to Google I guess.

Comment: The temporary solution: using `margin: <double of your font size> 0;` in `<p>` tag css to add a margin-top to every `<p>` tag instead of `<br>`. Works on both FF/Chrome for now.

Comment: @DanteY I can't make to work --> http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/xEF7h/55/

Comment: @Galled maybe I didn't make myself clear. This WILL still select the "blank", but now the blank will be in the same color as the highlight color you set for `::selection`

Comment: @DanteY ah ok! You are making the inverse, trying Firefox behaves like Chrome.

Comment: @Galled actually for both impl FF works normally (which the blank will not be selected, and the highlight would not overlays area outside of current div). I suppose this is a bug with Chrome rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need read [this question with all its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css).

By the way if you need to simulate this behavior in Chrome I think you can simulate a `<br/>` with `<span>`. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
p.normal::selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#ff0;
}
p.normal span::selection {
    background:#cc00ff;
    color:#ff0;
}
p.normal span {
    width:100%;
    clear:left;
    display: block;
    height: 1em;
}

p.moz::-moz-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#ff0;
}

p.webkit::-webkit-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#ff0;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>
    <p class="normal">Hello Normal
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    How are you?
    </p>
    <p class="moz">Hello Mozilla
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    How are you?
    </p>
    <p class="webkit">Hello Webkit
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    How are you?
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

After several tests, I concluded that to replicate the behavior in Chrome you would need a javascript that replicate [this styles](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/xEF7h/40/).

**EDIT2:**

To remove the pink border in the second line I make another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Galled/xEF7h/63/) (I think it's more clear).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However it doesn't really work out. I read the post before posting this and I tried `br::selection` as I mentioned in 2nd paragraph. I can see the override properties in firebug, but it is ignored by Chrome. Also I tried your `<span>` solution, not working either when I added `backgroud:xffffff` for `span.br::selection`, or added `-webkit-user-select:none`.

Comment: Well the idea is use the `<span>` instead `<br>`.

Comment: yes, I edit a bit your code and add new class called `span.br` and tried to add all properties I tried with `<br>` on it. In Chrome it is still selectable and highlight color doesn't change even you set a new one(e.g. your #cc0000).

Comment: @DanteY I updated my answer and I don't believe that the only way are CSS in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks it works. However I cannot get rid of the pink upper border which looks wired. Additionally this is really considered "hacked css". I will post my solution in my original post. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @DanteY I post another demo without the pink border. I could never imagine that Chrome would have problems with things like these.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set all `<br>` to be non selectable in css like so.

```css
br
{
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
    user-select: none; /* Standard */
}
```

```html
<p>Run the snippet to see for yourself.</p>
<br>
<p>See?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Nest `<br>` as the child of a `<p>`

```css
::selection {
  background: chartreuse;
}
div {
  padding: .3em;
}
div + div {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
code:before {
  content: "<";
}
code:after {
  content: ">";
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Layout is fine</p>
    <br>
    <p>but selection <del>isn't</del> <ins>wasn't (fixed in Chrome as of v 59.0.3071.115 or earlier)</ins></p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>One <code>br</code> in it's own <code>p</code> between this <code>p</code> </p>
    <p><br></p>
    <p>and this one</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Two <code>br</code>s nested in the end of this <code>p</code><br><br></p>
    <p>No <code>br</code>s in this <code>p</code>, and nothing between the <code>p</code></p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>No <code>br</code>s in this <code>p</code>, and nothing between the <code>p</code>s</p>
    <p><br>One <code>br</code>s nested in the start of this <code>p</code></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<hr/>` to replace `<br />` and then set its opacity to 0. Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GQXZx/).