# How to style the br tag to have more space at the top and / or at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

This question aims to understand more about the `<br>` tag:

There is an HTML page that uses the following style to break the words into paragraphs:

```
<div>
    <br>200 words follows...
    <br>another 300 words...
    <br>
    <br>and 250 words...
</div>
```

I normally wouldn't style content this way, but would use the `<p> ... </p>` tag for each paragraph.  But let's say we don't re-structure the document, but just use CSS to style the `<br>` tag so that each paragraph can have more empty space at the top (rather than none as the default), if **just for the purpose of understanding the `<br>` more**, how can that be done?  (although `<br>` is somewhat a special element for line break, it should be style-able like other elements.)

Note that `line-height` won't work in this case, and in Chrome, it works differently than in Firefox on a Mac... it can be tried at http://jsfiddle.net/ff5SX/2/

On Chrome, only 2 consecutive `<br>` would give more space, and on Firefox, the behavior is weird and is harder to explain.

Comment: Note: Use the <br> tag to enter line breaks, not to separate paragraphs.

Comment: Did you get an answer you can accept yet?

Answer (score 7):

This article sums up your styling possibilities(or rather impossibilities) for the br tag

[Can you target <br /> with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css)

Comment: does it sum up as: for cross-browser compatibility, it actually cannot be styled much at all, except for properties such as `clear` and `position`

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the following for a vertical gap of specified size**

**CSS**

div.verticalgap{clear:both;overflow:hidden;height:0px;}

**HTML (for a 10px vertical gap)**

<div class="verticalgap" style="height:10px"></div>