# Fake removing a break tag <br> with CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I've been trying to remove the line break that is caused by a break tag

I have come up with a solution that works in chrome, but not in firefox / IE11. Kind of curious if there is a CSS only solution that I could use in this situation that would work across most modern browsers:

HTML

```
<p>This line breaks in firefox,<br> but not chrome</p>
```

CSS

```
br {
    display: inline-block;
    content: " ";
    width: 7px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/T62LE/)

Edit:

1. The break tag also needs to act like a space between the two words.

Comment: Can you use `br {display: none;}` ? http://jsfiddle.net/yLUZD/

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to act like a space as well. Updating question

Comment: I don't think you can. Can't you just replace all the `<br/>`s with spaces? Either on the server or with JavaScript? `$("br").replaceWith(" ")` http://jsfiddle.net/T62LE/6/

Comment: @JuanMendes What ends up working is using display none and then adding a &nbsp; right after it. The current use case is something that has a line break on desktop, but not a line break on mobile. So I would like to use only CSS / HTML as it's not a functionality type thing.

Comment: Can you just use the space tag as the content? br{display: inline-block; content: "&nbsp;";}

Comment: @AndrewH You should test it. It doesn't work.

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex I think js is the only way to do it with cross browser support

Comment: Here's the current solution I'm using. Trying to avoid extra JS http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/8kD9G/

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex I think this is like the answer below but in css. br{display: none;}
br::after {content: "&nbsp;";}

Comment: @AndrewH That won't work either. You can't give a `br` a pseudo element.

Comment: [This is a relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css) :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few CSS methods and none of them are working in Firefox. I would suggest using a little bit of JavaScript to help you out.

Using jQuery, or just plain JS, insert a spacer element after each `<br>`

```
$('br').after('<span class="spacer"></span>');
```

The CSS:

```
br { display: none; }
.spacer { content: "\00a0"; }
```

Comment: If you're already using javascript, why go through the trouble of adding a spacer span instead of just replacing it with a space?

Comment: Because to switch back you'd just need to do `br { display: block; }`
`.spacer { display: none; }`.

If you simply replace the `<br>` elements, you have no obvious way to return to the original state. I suppose you could store the original content as a string in a variable though.

Comment: You could also just have a &nbsp; instead of a span.

Comment: Sure, but then what if you have other `&nbsp;`s that were there before? Now you've got `<br>`s where you don't want them.

Comment: `content: "&nbsp;";` will not render a space, it will print "&nbsp;"

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Need to convert html entities to hex to use them in CSS. `content: "\00a0";` Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following markup works cross browsers:

HTML

```
<div class="test">WORD<br>&nbsp;WITH<br>&nbsp;SPACE</div>
<div class="">WORD&nbsp;<br>WITH&nbsp;<br>SPACE</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test br{
    display: none;
}
```

Use case is if you want to have a 
 tag at a certain media query while still retaining spaces between the letters.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/8kD9G/)