# How to change line height of <br> and <span> elements?

Tags: html, css

The code below puts extra space between *some text* and *again some text*.

- Why is the `<br>` element between  `some text` and `again some text` not getting 0 height. I tried both `line-height: 0` and `height: 0`.
- The second `span` element's text in not taking 20px line-height, why?

**Note:** Please do not tell how to solve the problem. I only want to know why `line-height` works on `inline` elements like `span` this way.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.one {
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.two {
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 10px;
}
br {
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class=one>
    some text <br>
    agian some text <br>    
  </span>
  
  <span class="two">
    hip hop
  </span>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an `display:inline` element, you might need `display: inline-block` to see your changes.

Check below:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.one {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: grey;
}
.two {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
br {
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class=one>
    some text <br>
    agian some text <br>    
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="two">
    hip hop
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with `inline` elements? Doesn't line-height work on inline elements? And how to vertically align bottom the red hip hop text?

Comment: @user31782 : You can use `height` instead of `line-height` and `display: table-cell` to vertically align the element in bottom. Check the updated answer

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't style `<br>` tag but if you want know why check [it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css)

Also read about box-sizing [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

If you want set second `span` height exactly 20px use `min-height` property

Comment: If I shouldn't style `br` element then how do I reduce `br`;s height to 0?