# Styling a linebreak (<br>) inline with the text

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

Is it possible to style and position a line break right after a text node inline?

For example:

```css
br {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    border: 1px dotted green;
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: yellow;  
    color: blue;
    content: "A";
    width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<pre><div contenteditable="true">
some<BR />text with<BR />linebreaks.<BR />The intended result<BR />is to style the linbreak<BR />right after the sentence.<BR />
   </div>
 </pre>
```

The result from this code snippet almost achieves what I'm looking for, but it positions the visual representation of the line break on the next line.

The intended result is:

```
some"linebreak visual representation"
text with"linebreak visual representation"
linebreaks"linebreak visual representation"
The intended result"linebreak visual representation"
is to style the linebreak.."linebreak visual representation"
```

EDIT: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq7ckxq5/)

Comment: I think Firefox prevents the styling of `<br />`

Comment: `<br />` is an XML-ism, and unspecified in HTML. Though allowed, it does nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with Chrome (other browsers not tested)...

```css
br {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  font-size: 8px;
  line-height: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
  content: "A";
  width: 15px;
}
br:after {
  content: " Hello! \a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">some<BR />text with<BR />linebreaks.<BR />The intended result<BR />is to style the linbreak<BR />right after the sentence.<BR />
  </div>
```

**But** I strongly suggest you to [read this Török's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/899359/3219606), it seems there is no way to customize the `br` tag for all browsers. The reason is that *this element has no content*, it * generates a line-break and it is only a line-break*. *There are only few styles that make sense to apply on it, like `clear` or `position`. You can set BR's border but you won't see it as it has no visual dimension*.

You'd better use something as the `hr` tag to achieve what you need.

Comment: Dang, almost there. Just doesn't works with Firefox.

Comment: Add a comment as it seems imposible now to have a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hey br should be display: inline-block;

```css
br {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted green;
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: yellow;  
    color: blue;
    content: "A";
    width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<pre><div contenteditable="true">
some<BR />text with<BR />linebreaks.<BR />The intended result<BR />is to style the linbreak<BR />right after the sentence.<BR />
   </div>
 </pre>
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question maybe. I would still want for the lines to have layout line breaks.

Comment: Oh.. I actually just tried your code snippet with IE and it worked, but not with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that by adding `display:inline-block` property to your css. However, if you want only some `<br>` tags to have this ability you can add a class and assign the inline-block property to that class. That way you can combine two `<br>` tags, one with class and one without to get a new line and visible line breaks.

Comment: I would like to avoid having 2 linebreaks, defeats the purpose of the contenteditable, I would have to handle through javascript each linebreak delete.