# Cannot see line break <BR> when highlighted

Tags: css, html

In a div content editable, when highlighting, I can't see the thickness of the BR just like this:
[image]

I want it to be like this in MS Word

[image]

(Updated: Typo earlier -- wrong syntax as pointed out)
By the way, the `<BR>` is enclosed like this

```html
<div contenteditable='true'>
  <div>
    <span><br/></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Should I use CSS to set BR's thickness? or there's another way? Please shed some light.Thanks!

Comment: `</br>` should be `<br />`. your tag is invalid

Comment: See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u2er71gm/), you don't have anything to hilight because there isn't any character.
MSWord put blank space when you press enter/br

Comment: Browsers don't necessarily render things the same as MS Word. As far as I know, you can't "style" a `br`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css

Comment: what is the purpose of this? If you want to add some distance below a text line, why don't you just add a `margin-bottom`?

Comment: I just want that visual feed back that a line break/ new line is highlighted...

Comment: If my answer works, please @Desu give me "Best Answer" thanks.

Comment: @Dhn marked. thanks for the help

Comment: If you want visual feedback, how about line numbers or some other kind of line markings on the left hand side of the editable text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `&nbsp;` after `<br>` tag.

```html
<div contenteditable='true'>
<div>
<h4>test 1</h4>
<span>test
<br/>
<br/>
test
</span>
</div>

<div>
<h4>test 2 </h4>
<span>test
<br>
&nbsp;
<br>
test
</span>
</div>

<div>
<h4>test 3</h4>
<span>test
<br/>
&nbsp;
<br/>
test
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE :**

This works, because just like MSWord, you should put *white space* for a new line (`&nbsp;` for HTML). So you can highlight the text and see the new lines.

Comment: I agree that this is the way to achieve OP's goal. However, a little explanation surely couldn't hurt.

Comment: Updated @domdom