# Give <BR> thickness when highlighted

Tags: html, css

This is a followup to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507839/cannot-see-line-break-br-when-highlighted) which enables me to highlight and show that there's a newline inside a `div` however this is not limited to contenteditable div/WYSIWYG. Particularly, just a normal HTML page that contains an article. I just want to have that visual feedback that there's a newline when highlighted normally.

**THE QUESTION IS:**

Is it possible to see the `<br>`'s thickness without using Javascript and &nbsp when highlighted? Maybe some pure CSS which enable `<br>` act like a whitespace?

This question's motivation is to give `<br>` a thickness without putting **EXTRA** &nbsp or javascript manipulation if possible. Just give `<br>` a behavior of a non-breaking space character. Hitting two birds with one stone.

I searched for these references, [Can you target a breakline with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614928/change-br-height-using-css).

I already implemented a mock-up versions:

One that use JS which implements `selection` and `range` if the the `<br>` is within a range, change its style imitating a highlighted whitespace character.
*As far as possible, I don't want to use JS just to achieve this thing.*

and one that uses &nbsp that acts like a `<br>` within a span.

Moving on,

Yes, `<br>` is just an instruction to make a new line and it's not necessarily a character - not focusable like a whitespace character just like this (run code snippet)

```js
var sel = window.getSelection();
var newRange = document.createRange();

var spanTwo = document.getElementById("two");
var spanOne = document.getElementById("one");
var spanTextNode = spanTwo.firstChild;

newRange.setStart(spanOne,0);
newRange.setEnd(spanTextNode,spanTextNode.textContent.length);

sel.addRange(newRange);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <span id="one">He</span>
   <span><br></span>
   <span><br></span>
   <span id="two">He</span>
</body>
</html>
```

The highlight breaks at the middle and continues to the id two span instead. It can be fixed by inserting `&nbsp` though like this (Please run snippet):

```js
 var sel = window.getSelection();
    var newRange = document.createRange();

    var spanTwo = document.getElementById("two");
    var spanOne = document.getElementById("one");
    var spanTextNode = spanTwo.firstChild;

    newRange.setStart(spanOne,0);
    newRange.setEnd(spanTextNode,spanTextNode.textContent.length);

    sel.addRange(newRange);
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
      <span id="one">He</span>
       <span><br></span>
       <span>&nbsp<br></span>
       <span id="two">He</span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Again, the question's motivation is to give `<br>` a thickness without putting **EXTRA** &nbsp or javascript manipulation if possible. Just giving breakline a behavior of a non-breaking space.

**UPDATE**
Just to leave it here, further research, I found an example - it's facebook's editor (Draft.js)

[image]

Upon inspecting the DOM, it gives me:

```
<br data-text="true">
```

Which is highlight-able. I don't know if that's a fake `<br>` or a fake highlight produced by its JS rendering engine. I think that is a whitespace character at this instance because I can focus on it.

Anyway, thanks.