# Margin for br in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, margin, line-breaks

Is it possible to add margin for br tag in chrome? I have added mrgin property but that is not working in chrome. I had tried line heigth also. In firefox its working. This was my code

```
br{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 25px;    
}
```

Comment: try `line-height`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409649/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-br?scrlybrkr=b34b12d2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you target <br /> with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice.

```
br {
  content: "";
  margin: 20em;
  display: block;
  font-size: 24%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
content: '';
```

This will work in chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use line-height:

```css
br {
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p>dkajkjkdjkdjkd<br>dklsald</p>
```