# What CSS could i use to hide an item from this list

Tags: css

I'm wanting to just remove the line "Expires:Never" but can't seem to work it out how to hide it in CSS. Thanks!

```
<div class="mp_wrapper mp_users_subscriptions_list">
    <strong>
          <ul>
            <li class="">
                Basic Profile<br>
                Expires: Never                      
            </li>
          </ul>
    </strong>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<ul>` cannot be the child of `<strong>`.

Comment: If you want to just make "Expires: Never" invisible, it will need to be in it's own element. You can use `<span id='expiry'>Expires: Never</span>` and add the `display: none;` style for id `expiry` in your CSS

Comment: You can't target `<br>` with css selector. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css#899359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to put the `Expires: Never` in its own `div` or `span` and set `visibility` to `hidden`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a span and use display: none or visibility: hidden on it.