# How to select all paragraphs that follow a 'br' nested in 'P's using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

**In a nutshell: How do I select all paragraphs immediately following `<p><br></p>` using only CSS?**

**[EDIT] It seems that this is impossible with pure CSS, so I will open up the floor to anyone who knows how I can target such a string using simple/clean jQuery, given that the note editor in which I'm working is a jQuery editor. Thanks for checking it out.**

Longer explanation:

I am trying to set up some styling within a note program rich text editor so that it can be used for long-form writing.

Basically, most paragraphs need to have first-line indents. That is easy, I just add `p {text-indent: xem;}` in the `<style>` section.

However, when there is an extra `ENTER` keystroke (i.e. an extra space), I need the following line to NOT have an indent (i.e. `p {text-indent:0;}`).

Since these paragraphs follow an extra `ENTER` keystroke, these are the paragraphs immediately following `<p><br></p>` (the code generated by the editor I'm working in). That is the defining condition I need to target.

I am no professional coder, and so I have spent a couple of hours trying to figure out how to do this, unsuccessfully.

The problem is the fact that the `br` is automatically wrapped in `P` tags. For a standalone `br` tag, none of this is an issue - it works. But unfortunately, it is wrapped. This syntax actually works in my environment: `br + p {text-indent: 0;}`, however that only works with a standalone `br` tag.

I can't select the element via `:empty` and apply zero indent (i.e. `p:empty + p`) because it is not empty (contains the node `<br>`). (...is there a hack to make `:empty` ignore nodes?)

Hopefully there's someone with high-level knowledge who can let me know the best way - there must be a way..!

Adding HTML or jQuery is not an option - I will need to do this with CSS only.

Many thanks to anyone who can help with this one.

Comment: Go through this. You might get some clarity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css#:~:text=In%20effect%2C%20the%20element%20is,can%20do%20with%20other%20elements.

Comment: You can't do this with CSS only, you will need javaScript for this. In a couple of years you can do something like [p:has(br) + p {}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) ... Or do you only need the indent on the first paragraph? then it's possible.

Comment: @Anand - thanks for that. Yes that is a very closely-related question. I did go through that previously. Frustratingly, I have no problem targeting the <br> node. The issue is the fact that it is wrapped in `P` tags.

Comment: @cloned OK, that's what I feared. Well, I know that Query is enabled within the editor in question. I did make a mess of a jQuery attempt, but I don't really know much of it. Say there was a simple jQuery line or two that could achieve this. Could you share with me what it would look like? I am willing to try that. (The indent is needed for the paragraphs immediately after every instance of `<p><br></p>` throughout the document. Many thanks.